# Javascript loop through collection of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, refactoring

```
var squares = [1, 2, 4,  8];
var cubes = [1, 4, 9, 16];
var north,east,south,west;

north = getClass(squares[0], cubes[0]);
east  = getClass(squares[1], cubes[1]);
south = getClass(squares[2], cubes[2]);
west  = getClass(squares[3], cubes[3]);

$('.' + north).doStuff()
$('.' + east).doStuff()
$('.' + south).doStuff()
$('.' + west).doStuff()
```

I'm writing some code in javascript and it feels like I should be able to refactor this section but I don't know how to do it.

I think what I want to do is make north,east,south,west into some sort of collection so that i can iterate through it?

How would you recommend I do this with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way :

```
var squares = [1, 2, 4,  8];
var cubes = [1, 4, 9, 16];

for(var i=0; i< squares.length; i++)
{
     $('.' + getClass(squares[i], cubes[i])).doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like that :

```
var squares = [1, 2, 4,  8];
var cubes = [1, 4, 9, 16];
var selectors = [];

for(var c = 0, c < squares.length, c++){
    selectors.push(getClass(squares[c], cubes[c]));
}

$('.' + selectors.join(', .')).doStuff()
```

Alternatively, you could use `.map` :

```
var squares = [1, 2, 4,  8];
var cubes = [1, 4, 9, 16];
var selectors = $.map(squares, function(_, i){
    return getClass(squares[i], cubes[i]);
})

$('.' + selectors.join(', .')).doStuff()
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var squares = [1, 2, 4,  8];
var cubes = [1, 4, 9, 16];
var direction=[]
for (i=0;i<cubes.length;i++){
    a.push(getClass(squares[i], cubes[i]));
}
$(a).each(function (index) {
    $('.' + this).doStuff();
});
```